# Unable to iterate over json values with jq

Tags: jq

I'm building a list of RDS instances in AWS. Working with local json file for now.

I am able to get up to the `'.DBInstances[].DBSubnetGroup[]'` level in the [ORIGINAL JSON](https://gist.github.com/bluethundr/092ca6e39016188f56d8b46b203be06d) file. With this command:

```
jq -r '.DBInstances[].DBSubnetGroup[]' ab-prod-rds.json
```

But I am unable to get at the information in the `'.DBInstances[].DBSubnetGroup[].Subnets.SubnetStatus'` level of the same.

When I give this command: `jq -r '.DBInstances[].DBSubnetGroup[].Subnets.SubnetStatus' ab-prod-rds.json`

The error I get is: `jq: error (at ab-prod-rds.json:618): Cannot index array with string "Subnets"`

What am I doing wrong? How can I format the query to access this info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a number of issues in your query. The types in your hierarchy of objects are:

- (root) - object
- DBInstances - array of object
- DBSubnetGroup - object
- Subnets - array of object

You generally don't want to use `[]` on objects as it will just enumerate over all values when all you really want is a specific property.

If you just want to output all the subnet statuses, your query should be this:

```
.DBInstances[].DBSubnetGroup.Subnets[].SubnetStatus
```